# How do I add an @onclick function on dynamically generated/manipulated HTML?

Tags: c#, blazor

I've got some code, which searches through a text string, and replaces all instances of a certain substring with an element containing an onclick function. It looks something like this:

```
private string ReplaceCitationLinks(string text, int documentIndex)
{
    for (var i = 1; i <= documentIndex; i++)
    {
        var html = "<span class='citation-link' @onclick='() => ShowCitation(" + i + ")'>(Dokument " + i + ")</span>";
        text = text.Replace("[doc" + i + "]", html);    
    }

    return text;
}
```

and is then called in the HTML:

```
@((MarkupString)ReplaceCitationLinks("Test string [doc1]. Test string [doc2]", item.Citations.Count))
```

So in this case, I want only the [doc1] and [doc2] parts of the string to be clickable. The problem is that the @onclick doesn't work. I figure I might need to do this some other way. Does anyone know how I would accomplish this?

Comment: Well, what is the form factor of the clickable area?  You can just put it inside a `<div>` tag, and add the `@onclick` to that.  Generally, avoid using MarkupStrings if at all possible, and use Components instead, with whatever the MarkupString build has in it.

Comment: Markup is compiled into `RenderTreeBuilder` code at compile time, you are trying to do it at runtime.  There are almost certainly better ways.  How do you generate `Test string [doc1]. Test string [doc2]`

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that Blazor does not know that your markup contains Blazor syntax like `@onclick`.

There are several approaches to solve this, but I would recommend to create a component `TextRenderer`. In this component you add a parameter `Text` to receive the text and a parameter `OnSpanClick`. Then override `BuildRenderTree`, parse the text to find out the position of the placeholders, then return non-placeholder markup as is and call suitable methods on `RenderTreeBuilder` to build you `span` syntax, like

```
protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
{
  // parse 'Text' to find placeholder positions

  // iterate over 'Text' in steps defined by the placeholder positions,
  // for example, start with 0, then jump to first placeholder at postion 10, then to second placeholder at position 56, etc.

  // in those steps above, decide whether the text range is normal markup, then return it as

  builder.AddContent(..., textRange);

  // otherwise build your clickable span like

  builder.OpenElement(..., "span");
  builder.AddAttribute(..., "onclick",
    EventCallback.Factory.Create(owner,
      async () => await OnSpanClick.InvokeAsync(documentNumber)));
  builder.AddContent(..., $"Dokument {documentNumber}");
  builder.CloseElement();
}
```

Then use this component where needed like

`<TextRenderer Text="@..." OnSpanClicked="@..." />`

Comment: Thank you the response. It seems like I cannot override BuildRenderTree in a new Razor component, though.  I get the error "Type '' already defines a member called 'BuildRenderTree' with the same parameter types." even though there's no cases of the "BuildRenderTree" member in any of my code.

Comment: Try it with a code behind file and inherit the class defined in this file from `ComponentBase`